# Why is the code generated for "Hello World" program 10 times larger for C++ than for C?

Tags: c++, c

This in is the FAQ I recently read on [Dr. Bjarne Stroustrup's web site](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#Hello-world). I also tested a simple "Hello World" program in C and then in C++, and surprisingly the size of a C++ "Hello World" program executable file is 1357 KB (1.32 MB) whereas the size of the executable file in C is only 122 KB. Why there is such a huge difference in the size between the C "Hello World" Program and the C++ "Hello World" Program?

http://stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#Hello-world

I am using Orwell Dev-C++ compiler. I used option "Strip executable" & recompile it. After doing this size reduces to 12 KB in C and 536 KB in C++.

Comment: Didn't he already explained it there?

Comment: @Ashalynd: explain more clearly what u r saying?

Comment: This depends on how your program is compiled/builded. At first try to compare just object files (`-c` switch in `gcc`). Then you need to know if your program is builded with static or shared runtime libraries. Total size for first one is of course larger than second.

Comment: There is more wiring to be set in place for a C++ program. Usually you don't link these parts to your program statically, because they are supposed to be available via the shared libraries present in the system (a little bit like Java programs require Java to be installed in order to run). In case of C++ though,  you can make your C++ program self-contained, on cost of increasing its size.

Comment: `g++ -O2 -o hello hello.cpp && strip hello` <-- This gave me a 6656 byte executable (built with gcc 4.8.2 in Cygwin).

Comment: `g++ -O2 -o hello hello.cpp && strip hello` <-- 6272 bytes on Ubuntu 14.10, `gcc 4.8.2`. 6376 bytes with `clang++3.4.1`
Code was:
`#include <iostream>
int main(){ std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl; }`

Comment: Yes, as Grzegorz says, take the .obj files to compare. The size of the .exe depends mostly on the linked libraries and so on the development environment.

Comment: @Philm: are you sure? Compiling code with the same compiler and on the same environment, with (as far as possible) the same optimizations and linker settings surely should not differ that much? That is what the OP did.

Comment: With `g++ -O2 hello.cpp` and `gcc -O2 hello.c` I get 49KB and 46KB respectively. Adding the `strip` gives me 17KB and 16KB respectively. The results are always going to be dependent on the optimization levels and linked libraries.

Comment: @Ashalynd good analogy with Java, but just want to make sure... you do know the difference between the C/C++ stdlibs versus a Java installation?

Comment: I hope I do :) C/C++ programs don't run inside VM, of course.

Comment: @Ashalynd They might.  See for instance [emscripten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emscripten)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a comparison of binary filesize of c and c++ hello world programs when compiled with gcc: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46126d97d45fba1a

The size difference between c and c++ on that platform is 240 bytes for both stripped and non-stripped executable which is quite insignificant in my opinion.

As Stroustrup writes on the page that you've linked:

> It is all an issue on how an implementor organizes the standard libraries (e.g. static linking vs. dynamic linking, locale support by default vs. locale support enabled through and option, etc.). If one version is significantly larger than the other, report the problem to the implementor of the larger.

Stroustrup doesn't specify how much should be considered "significant", but if your compiler produces 10x bigger binary for an identical hello world program, a bug report may be appropriate.

Comment: You are talking about object code file or executable file?

Comment: I'm talking about the executable.

Comment: OTOH, 240 bytes is **more** than enough to write a "Hello world" program with `debug`. (I just found out `debug` is missing in Windows 7, which is too bad 'cause now I can't *prove* it! But I'm eyeballing `hello.com` to be 21 bytes -- again, a factor of 10x smaller, as it happens. (That is, 10 times smaller than the *difference*).)

Comment: More than enough indeed :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284797/hello-world-in-less-than-20-bytes

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your compiler, and what environment you use. If you link statically then you will be including the standard library in your executable, while typically this is done dynamically since the standard library can vary on different platforms (though I suppose you'd compile separately for those anyway). Also, it does bloat your executable's file size, as you have seen here.

Try linking dynamically to the standard library, you may have to copy the library binaries into the same directory with your executable. The file size will probably be very similar after this.